# How do I formulate a proof by equivalences in english?

Tags: proof-writing

I have a proof of the form

> **Theorem.** $A \iff \forall x D$.
>
> *Proof.*
> \begin{align}
> A &\iff \forall x B 
> \\ & \iff \forall x C
> \\ & \iff \dots
> \\ & \iff \forall x D
> \end{align}
> QED.

Note that $A$, $B$, $C$, etc are simply placeholders for more complex expressions/full sentences occuring in an real proof.
What is the best way to write such a proof as English opposed to symbolically?
This is my first attempt:

> *Proof*.
> $A$ is true if and only if for all $x$
> \begin{align}
>   B, && \text{(by definition 1)}
> \end{align}
> if and only if for all $x$
> \begin{align}
>   C
> \end{align}
> if and only if for all $x$
> \begin{align}
>   \dots
> \end{align}
> if and only if for all $x$
> \begin{align}
>   D. && \text{(by lemma 3)}
> \end{align}
> QED.

The proof feels too verbose and monotonous. I also find it tiresome to repeat the clause "if and ony if for all $x$" for every step.

I considered using the following style:

> *Proof*.
> $A$ is true if and only if for all $x$
> \begin{align}
>   & B, && \text{(by definition 1)}
>   \\ &\text{if and only if}\quad C,
>   \\ &\text{if and only if}\quad \dots
>   \\ &\text{if and only if}\quad D. && \text{(by lemma 3)}
> \end{align}
> QED.

But I'm not sure this says the same thing, because $\textrm{false} \iff \textrm{false}$.

Is there any way to streamline my proof?

Comment: Why is $false \iff false$ a problem?

Comment: I believe there is a difference between the statements

(i) $A \iff \forall x B \iff \forall x C$

and

(ii) $A \iff \forall x (B \iff C)$ 

Isn't it the case that:

sentence (i) is **false** if $A$ is true and both $\forall x B$ and $\forall x C$ are false.

sentence (ii) is **true** if $A$ is true and both $\forall x B$ and $\forall x C$ are false.

Answer (score 4):

The point of a proof is to convince the reader that your argument is sound. To that end, streamlining should not be your goal. Verbose is OK if it's instructive. Do avoid monotony. There is no algorithm for writing a good proof. Mathematical exposition is an art.

Absent the details about $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ in your example I might suggest something like:

> Proof:
>
> Definition $1$ tells us that $A$ is true if and only if $B$ is true
> for all $x$. That is equivalent to $C$ because $\ldots$.
>
> $\ldots$
>
> Finally, Lemma $3$ shows that is in turn equivalent to $D$, and we're
> done.

Notes.

- Most proofs are sequences of implications, not logical equivalences.
  That allows for more varied wording.
- If you have a sequence of equivalences as in this example, you might
  want to state the theorem in the form "The following statements are
  equivalent". I once proved such a theorem, with the implication chains $A \implies B \implies C \implies D \implies A$ and $C \implies E \implies F \implies B$,
- If in your paper the statements $A$, $B$, $\ldots$ are all short and
  the equivalences more or less routine, then the compact exposition
  might be best.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm still a bit hesitant about omitting the "for all $x$" in some places, as is done before $C$ in your example. That is because think the variable is scoped to the sentence where the $for all$ occurs. If so, then I think that the style starting with "the following are equivalent", must also have "for all x" at the start of each expression.

Comment: I was not suggesting that omission, just proposing a structure. Obviously you put in the details you think are necessary.